# ARAnchorManager not auto spawning resolved ARCloudAnchors on iOS

Tags: ios, arcore, ar-foundation

I am able to host an ARCloudAnchor from both Android and iOS successfully. However I am unable to resolve an ARCloudAnchor on iOS; whether the iOS device hosted the anchor itself or received the ARCloudAnchor.Id from another device.

I have an ARAnchorManager configured with a prefab and it auto creates and displays the GameObject on Android whenever I resolve an ARCloudAnchor Id. On iOS ResolveCloudAnchorPromise completes successfully and even seems to have fetched the anchor properly but the ARAnchorManager never spawns a GameObject using the prefab. I can tell the anchor fetched is right because if I manually create a GameObject myself and attach an anchor who's Pose matches the resolved ARCloudAnchor's Pose the position looks right.

I am also waiting on the ARAnchorManager.anchorsChanged event before hosting a cloud anchor and on the feature map to be "Good" before attempting to resolve a cloud anchor.

Like Android, I expect the ARAnchorManager on iOS to auto spawn a GameObject using the resolved ARCloudAnchor. Does anyone know if there is some extra config needed or if this is WAI?